# How to set cron job run at 09 19 29 39 49 59 minutes in every hour

Tags: cron, jobs

I want to set cron job run at 09 19 29 39 49 59 minutes in every hour, for example in 00:09, 00:19, 00:29, 00:39, 00:49, 00:59 and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list arbitrary values on cronjob expressions, by separating them with commas.

For you case, what you want is: `9,29,39,49,59 * * * *`